# How can I store a permanent variable on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am creating a webpage with a simple form on it. When the form is submitted, I would like a variable, call it number, to increment by one. When the form is submitted, I would like the variable to permanently increment by one, and then hold that value until the form is submitted again. By this, I mean that say I submit the form for the first time, the counter will go from 0 to 1. A week later, some other person can submit the form and the counter will go from 1 to 2, and so on. How can I go about doing this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does **permanently** mean for you? For their current session **permanently** or for their (logged in) user? Clientside or Serverside?

Comment: Sounds like you want to build a counter that persists through all sessions, so something like localStorage on a clients browser or sessionStorage isn't appropriate.  You'll need to look at a data store, maybe SQL or Mongo.

Comment: Are u want to so this permanent variable in webpage? here you can store one variable in DB and when form is submit that time you can increament

Comment: use cookies http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Depends on if you mean to [store it in the browser for that particular user](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+persist+data+between+sessions&t=hn&ia=qa) or [share the data between all visitors](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=introduction+to+server+side+programming&t=hn&ia=web)

Comment: You can also use local storage

Comment: I would like a counter that persists through all sessions, so let's say I submit the form, the counter goes from 0 to 1. A week later, someone else can submit the form and the counter will go from 1 to 2, and so on.

Comment: You could even keep it real simple and just have a text file at the backend with a number in it which get incremented every the form is submitted. 

Which ever way you slice it you're going to need some way of storing the data on the server side in a non-volatile method (ie. no application variables that get wiped when the site winds down due to no recent connections).

Comment: you can't do that with frontend-javascript. so the tags for your question aren't right. declare which server-language you are going to use.

Comment: What can you use? PHP/Node.js? SQL/file based storage/NoSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update a simple database table using Ajax or PHP. Javascript itself is not able to write server-side content.